# Start MacOs .app with golang's exec.command library

Tags: macos, go, unix, exec

I have an MacOS .app application in a folder that I need to start using exec.Command(), however it won't run because it claims that the app does not exist even if it does.

```
cmd = exec.Command("open", `Example\ Application.app`)
cmd.Dir = <dir to file>
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    return err
}
fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
```

If I type this exact command with the same exact path into a terminal window, it runs. However it just won't run in Go, with the output.
`exit status 1: The file Example\ Application.app does not exist.`
I can even run "ls" as a command in the parent directory and it displays that that file is there.

Comment: An `.app` file is actually just a folder/directory.  Your command is expecting an executable binary, which is probably located in `Example Application.app/Contents/MacOS/`

Comment: I tried that as well, it wouldn't even let me go into the directory as it claimed that also did not exist

Comment: You don't need to "go into" anything... you need to specify the binary executable path, not just the directory in which it is located.

Comment: I guess you do not need the `\ ` part, exec will escape spaces for you, so just pass "Example Application.app". If this happens to be the actual problem, I will create an answer for you to except, if not, never mind :-)

Comment: Run `open --help` and figure out the correct command line switch for your use case.